# how do I remove my git repo references from Team Explorer Connect [pic included]

Tags: git, github, visual-web-developer

I've deleted my git repo online at git hub. However, I can't seem to get rid of them in my visual studio. Any idea on how to remove it?

[image]

For e.g. there is no project called deostrap anymore. I've kind of renamed that in github. How do I remove this now from my visual studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right-click on the git project name you should get an option to remove:

[image]

But sometimes you don't see that Remove menu item enabled!

Well in that case, just navigate to the folder where the git project is located and delete or relocate that folder. When you come back to Team Explorer Connect right-click again, you should see the menu item enabled.